# Pegar num valor de outro campo sem ser o id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, tabela-html

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

1 - AtribuicaoLuvas com os seguintes campos: Id, NumPedido, Colaborador e DataAtribuicao.

2 - EstadoLuvas com os seguintes campos: id, IdEstado e Estado.

O NumPedido é igual ao IdEstado.

Agora quero que ao inserir na tabela AtribuicaoLuvas que também me insira na tabela EstadoLuvas, mas quero que me vá buscar o valor do NumPedido da primeira tabela automaticamente e me insira na tabela EstadoLuvas no campo IdEstado.

**Se fosse para pegar no id usava o seguinte código:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO AtribuicaoLuvas (NumPedido,Colaborador,DataAtribuicao)
VALUES ('$pedido','$colaborador','$data')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO EstadoLuvas (`IdEstado`,`Estado`) 
VALUES ('$last_id','$estado')"; 

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);
```

mas neste caso como faço?

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor? não entendi muito bem o que você quer

Comment: No primeiro insert o value do `NumPedido` é = `$pedido`, daí no segundo insert faça o value do `IdEstado` = `$pedido`

Comment: Leo caracciolo, obrigado pela dica. Resolvi o meu problema

Answer (score -1):

Considerando que você está usando PDO.

Primeiro vamos "prepare()" a query, trocando os valores enviado pelo usuário por ? (isso resolve também o problema de SQL injection).

No "execute()" você envia um array com o valor de cada campo.

Se o código de erro == 00000 então deu tudo certo.

```
<?php 
$sql = "INSERT INTO AtribuicaoLuvas (NumPedido, Colaborador, DataAtribuicao) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$consulta = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$consulta->execute(array($pedido, $colaborador, $data);

if ($consulta->errorCode() == '00000') {
  $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

  $sql = "INSERT INTO EstadoLuvas (`IdEstado`,`Estado`) VALUES (?, ?)"; 

  $consulta = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $consulta->execute(array($last_id, $estado);
}
?>
```